# php curl to instagram returns odd result

Tags: php, curl, instagram

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php'); 

    $usuario = "username";
    $password = "password";

    $url = 'https://www.instagram.com/';
    $url_login = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/';
    $user_agent = array("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ",
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36");

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    $headers = [
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Content-Length: 0',
    'Host: www.instagram.com',
    'Origin: https://www.instagram.com',
    'Referer: https://www.instagram.com/',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36', 
    'X-Instagram-AJAX: 1',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'  
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie/pruebalogininsta2.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $sTarget);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $html, $matches);
    $cookies = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
        parse_str($item, $cookie);
        $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
    }


    $headers = [
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    //'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Content-Length: 0',
    'Host: www.instagram.com',
    'Origin: https://www.instagram.com',
    'Referer: https://www.instagram.com/',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36', 
    'X-Instagram-AJAX: 1',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
    ];

    $cadena_agregar_vector = 'X-CSRFToken:'. $cookies["csrftoken"];

    $headers[] = $cadena_agregar_vector ;

    $sPost =  "username=".$usuario . "&password=". $password ;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);  

    $html2 = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.instagram.com/");  

    $html4 = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $html4;
```

this is what I get[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the way you hardcode `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`, this makes curl send the encoding header indeed, but it does not turn on the decoding feature of curl, thus you get the raw data, without curl decoding it for you.

remove `'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'`, and add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');` , and curl will decode it for you (provided that curl is compiled with gzip & deflate support) - or better yet, just do `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');` , and curl will automatically list all supported encodings, so you dont run into the encoding problem where curl isn't compiled with gzip support.

on an unrelated note, you probably want to use CURLOPT_USERAGENT, not set the user-agent header manually. else, the UA-string will just be sent with this 1 request, and be reset on the next request, while CURLOPT_USERAGENT is kept until curl_close($ch)

edit: on my first revision of this post, i wrote CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS instead of CURLOPT_ENCODING, sorry, fixed that

edit 2: on another unrelated note, you're encoding the username/password wrong. instead of `$sPost =  "username=".$usuario . "&password=". $password ;`, do
`$sPost=http_build_query(array('username'=>$usuario,'password'=>$password));`, else accounts with & or = or NULLs in the password or username wont work properly

Comment: I didnt understand what you meant with " else accounts with & or = or NULLs in the password or username wont work properly" ? Can you phrase it another way?

Comment: @Pablo make an account with the password `Adam&Eve=Human` , and you'll see what i mean. it will try to log in with the wrong password, because `&` and `=` is not encoded properly. the correct encoding, as http_build_query would give you, is actually `Adam%26Eve%3DHuman`

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by @hanshenrik should really be accepted. But if you just want an easy solution that works and is not incorrect, remove the `'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'` from your headers array.